# Search custom fields with multiple records

Tags: custom-fields, search, multi-record

I'm not really sure how to describe this but  hopefully I can describe it clear enough.

I created a custom field set that holds borrowing information for items (like tools, equipment, etc.). It has 3 fields (actually more, but here 3 is enough to describe the problem): Item name, Date borrowed, Date returned.

A contact can borrow multiple items at once.

Is there a way to search for contacts who have not borrowed *any* item in the last 6 months?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to do an exclude search.

Create a smart group that has all the people who have borrowed a tool in the last 6 month.  Create another smart group that contains everyone.

Under Search => Custom Searches you should find the custom search "Include / Exclude Contacts in a Group / Tag".

Include your group that contains everyone.
Exclude your group that contains the people who have borrowed.
This should result in the people who haven't borrowed.